# Editable QComboBox: synchronize edit text with item text

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qcombobox

I've got a `QComboBox` which I want to be "automatically" editable. That is, every time a user manually changes current item's text, that text should "fall" to the underlying model automatically.

So far, I've reached this via a custom signal handler:

```
void setupUi() {
    ...
    connect( someComboBox,
             SIGNAL(editTextChanged(QString)),
             SLOT(comboBoxEditTextChanged(QString)) );
    ...
}

void comboBoxEditTextChanged( const QString& text ) {
    someComboBox->setItemText( someComboBox->currentIndex(), text );
}
```

So I wonder, is there a possibility to do this with less code? I've tried `QComboBox::setInsertPolicy(QComboBox::InsertAtCurrent)`, but that didn't help.

**EDIT:** Current method with a custom slot works properly - but I'm asking if there's a method that *does not involve* any signals/slots.

Comment: The whole point of model/view pattern is that views (QComboBox) only DISPLAY data. Therefore in your given example you only change data in QCombobox's internal buffer (the model should not get changed). Your slot should operate on the model, not the view

Answer (score 2):

To set the Text Automatically when USER changes it, we can edit your slot as follows:

```
void comboBoxEditTextChanged( const QString& text ) 
{
    int index = someComboBox->findText(text);
    if(index != -1)
    {
      someComboBox->setCurrentIndex(index);
     }
    someComboBox->setItemText( someComboBox->currentIndex(), text );
}
```

I hope this will resolve your issue

Comment: This isn't it again... I want the text that user enters to be saved to the model under current index, so no need in searching. Moreover, current method works OK - but I wonder if it can be done without signals/slots and without copying strings at each character input.

Answer (score -1):

QComboBox can add items manually using

```
combo->additem("X"); 

combo->addItem(QString Y);
```

whereas you can manage the maximum number of items in it. Please go through the following link for details.

[a link](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Archived%3aHow_to_use_QComboBox_in_Qt)

So, in your slot,

```
void comboBoxEditTextChanged( const QString& text ) 
{
    someComboBox->addItem(text);
}
```

Comment: Well, I do not need to add new items, I just need to change text of existing items - preferably without using custom slots.

Comment: @intelfx
Its my mistake. I did'nt read ur question correctly. Well we can do it in following way

int index = combo->findText(text);
if ( index != -1 ) { // -1 for not found
   combo->setCurrentIndex(index);
}